# Using OleDB to get Excel Sheet Data, but it's "randomly" not reading cell data of a row

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, oledb

I'm currently attempting to extract certain data from thousands of excel files. But this problem is driving me absolutely crazy and I'm in a time-crunch to get this all of these done before a short deadline.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be retrieving ALL of the data, in particular, these "option" columns as I call them. It's supposed to have -01 all the way to -10 for this particular sheet. These are the only values on the entire sheet that are sometimes not read in. They are sometimes slanted at a 45 degree angel, but it doesn't seem to make a difference if I change their orientation manually before reading the file in.

This is what it's doing:
[image: Missing certain cells' data...]

This is the excel file in question (not sure if that link will work):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7-iwpcLS0GoaVpHYkxPTWdIYUE/view?usp=sharing

Direct download link if that Google spreadsheet fails:
http://www.filedropper.com/123456_1

This is the basic code I'm using ripped out of my application:

```
Dim xlAppIn As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbookIn As Excel.Workbook = xlAppIn.Workbooks.Open(sFilename)
xlAppIn.Visible = False

Dim oleDbConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & sFilename & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR=No; IMEX=1'"
Dim oleDbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(oleDbConnStr)
oleDbConn.Open()

Dim sSheetName As String = xlWorkbookIn.Sheets(1).Name.ToString()
txtStatus.Text = sSheetName

'Dim oleDbCmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & sSheetName & "$B5:AI46]", oleDbConn)
Dim oleDbCmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & sSheetName & "$]", oleDbConn)
Dim oleDbDa As New OleDbDataAdapter(oleDbCmd)

Dim dt As New DataTable
oleDbDa.Fill(dt)
dgvRaw.DataSource = dt
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe it's my connection string? Or maybe the file-type is too old? It's probably an old excel file, made with who-knows what version, etc. I'm at a loss.

Comment: It looks correct to me.   Note:  The original Excel sheet has row 26 with zero height....but it's there.

Comment: I've added a download link: http://www.filedropper.com/123456_1 Just in case it's some sort of weird excel version problem and you guys can possibly load it up as well and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally figured it out, but I'm not sure why it matters.

I had to format the cells to text inside of Excel and save it before attempting to load the file with my program. Some of the cells I guess were not formatted as text, so it would just not bother reading it in.

I even tested without IMEX=1 and the same thing happened.

---

Now it'd be nice if there was a way to automate that in a *quick* fashion.
e.g.: open the file, format all sheets text, and then read from it.

Figured that out as well...

```
'nSheetPos being iterator for looping through the sheets in the workbook
xlWorkbookIn.Sheets(nSheetPos).Columns.NumberFormat = "@"
xlWorkbookIn.Save()
```